# Stick a button and an arrow to the cursor when hovering

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a button, when you hover over it, it starts to magnetize to the cursor, but the content (arrow) remains in place, but I need it to magnetize too, how can this be done?

An example is on this site https://www.m-trust.co.jp/, and here is my code

I searched the forums, tried it myself, but nothing works :(

```js
function btnRun() {

  // Двигающаяся кнопка
  let offset = 70,
    cur = false;

  document.body.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(e) {
    if (e.target.classList.contains('btn') && cur === false) {
      cur = {
        e: e.target,
        x: e.target.getBoundingClientRect().left,
        y: e.target.getBoundingClientRect().top
      };
    }
  }, true);

  document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    if (cur !== false) {
      let x = (e.clientX - cur.x) - (cur.e.getBoundingClientRect().width / 2),
        y = (e.clientY - cur.y) - (cur.e.getBoundingClientRect().height / 2);
      cur.e.style.transform = `translate(${x}px,${y}px)`;
      //
      if (Math.abs(x) >= offset || Math.abs(y) >= offset) {
        cur.e.style.transform = 'translate(0,0)';
        cur = false;
      }
    }
  });

}

btnRun();
```

```css
.btn {
  position: relative;
  width: 69px;
  height: 69px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 0px;
  background: #FF625B;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 29px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-top: 15px;
  transition: transform .2s linear;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

span {
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.intro {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background: #447EF0;
}

.intro__inner {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.intro__content {
  width: 50%;
}

.intro__content__title {
  color: #FFF;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  padding-top: 173px;
}

.intro__content__text {
  color: #fff;
  max-width: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.intro__block__btn {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.intro__text__btn {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #fff;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 25px;
}

.intro__block__img {
  max-width: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 102px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  padding-right: 100px;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

.intro__img {
  float: right;
  max-width: 674px;
  width: 100%;
}

.intro__footer {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.intro__info {
  width: 95%;
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 45px;
  padding-bottom: 80px;
  color: #fff;
}

.intro__info span {
  padding-right: 7px;
}

.intro__info h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding-right: 80px;
}

.intro__info h2:last-child {
  padding-right: 0px;
}

.intro__h2__one {
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="intro__block__btn">
  <p class="intro__text__btn">Записаться </p>
  <a href="#form" class="btn btn-intro">
    <span>--></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code works for me in Chrome

Comment: For me, the button and the text in it both follow the cursor the same way (Chrome & Firefox). (BTW, if you don't know about it, there's also [ru.so].)

Comment: It is necessary that not only the button moves behind the mouse, but that the line in it also creates a 3D effect.

Comment: Knew, I asked for help there, but they didn’t help me :(

Answer (score 0):

Your code works well in CodeSandBox and my Edge.(comment some code)

https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-jennings-kl3d5

if it's not work on your browser,you can try it in other browser or platform

Comment: You misunderstood the question a little. The button moves, the content in the button (relative to the button) itself, it stays in place, but I need the arrow to move in the button in the same direction as the button, and so it stays in place (relative to  button)

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.